# Is there any method to clear the images with python?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, pixel

I have a lot of image like this:

[image: Imagen 1]

[image: Imagen 2]

Is there any method that allows me to clarify the background of the images using python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use openCV lib for this purpose. There are a lot of functions to this.

Basically you can target the white color range of the background by using **thresholding** methods. See example [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html).